# react change style depends on text

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to show my list with their own styling depending on the text they contain.

```
function TypeFilter() {
  const { filterOpen, TypeList } = useGlobalContext();
  return (
    <div className={filterOpen ? "ft-filter show-filter" : "ft-filter"}>
      <div className="filter-wrapper">
        {TypeList.map((type, index) => {
          const { name } = type;
          return (
            <div className="filter-btn" key={index}>
              {name}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here, the text is on the `{name}`, is there a way for me to achieve that?

Comment: A standard `if(name==='example')` used to append a style would work, what sort of text-to-styling are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do not use index as your key. It is not the best practice.

Comment: Only because `index` is a number - you can simply use `index.toString()` instead.

Comment: @DBS I want to change the color of each name.

Comment: @TusharShahi I got the data from a public API that has no ID, so I don't have any idea how to create the key. And I thought it won't be a problem since there won't any changes on the list

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally add class name to your div. You need to add styles in your css file for that new classnames.

```
function TypeFilter() {
  const { filterOpen, TypeList } = useGlobalContext();
  return (
    <div className={filterOpen ? "ft-filter show-filter" : "ft-filter"}>
      <div className="filter-wrapper">
        {TypeList.map((type, index) => {
          const { name } = type;
          const nameClass = name === 'your-condition' ? 'red' : 'blue';
          return (
            <div className=`filter-btn ${nameClass}` key={index}>
              {name}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If name matches the criteria, assign it the desired class

```
       {TypeList.map((type, index) => {
          const { name } = type;

          let textClass;
          if (name === "banana") textClass = "banana-class";
  

          return (
            <div className={`filter-btn ${textClass}`} key={index}>
              {name}
            </div>
          );
        })}
```